# Python: Importing submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to set up a new Python project with the following structure:

```
project:
   src:
      app1:
         main.py
      utils:
         __init__.py
         utils1:
            __init__.py
            utils1.py
   tests:
```

I would like to import utils1 in main.

I tried the following from main.py but it does not work:

```
main.py

from project.src.utils.utils1 import utils1
```

This indicates the following error:

```
(virtualenv)user: /home/user/project/src/app1 $ python main.py
   ImportError: No module named 'project'
```

How can I import utils1 in main correctly?

Comment: First, don't skip `src` in the import (project . **src** . utils). Second, you probably need to turn `project` and `src` into packages (place `__init__.py` there). Third, I'm not sure if relative imports beyond the top-level module will work, so you may need to put `project` in the python search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `__init__.py` in project directory, so `project` isn't recognised as a package. The same goes with src directory.

Besides, you're running from app1 directory, so directories above it aren't visible in pythonpath.

Change directory to `~/project/src`, move `utils` directory to `app1`, run `./app1/main.py` and `import app1.utils.utils1.utils1`

In the end:

Your layout should look like:

```
project:
   src:
      app1:
         main.py
         utils:
            __init__.py
            utils1:
               __init__.py
               utils1.py
   tests:
```

Execute as:

```
(virtualenv)user: /home/user/project/src $ python ./app1/main.py
```

And import as:

```
from app1.utils.utils1 import utils1
```

Comment: `(virtualenv) user:/home/user/project/src $ python ./app1/main.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./app1/main.py", line 1, in <module>
        from utils.utils1 import utils1
    ImportError: No module named 'utils'`

Comment: At the very beginning of main.py please do: import sys; print sys.path - we'll see if it doesn't see the utils dir, or you have wrong file layout

Comment: sys.path contains '/home/user/project/src/app1". All other folders are system folders from the virtual environment.

Comment: Fair enough. Editing the answer, I'll change the approach a bit - we're gonna move utils to app1 package. See if it works now.

Comment: That works. But my wish is to maintain the utils in src since I plan to bring more apps into this project which will need the utils.

Comment: Welp, python isn't really good at making wishes come true. Zen of python contains line "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." and because of that you probably won't be able to achieve your custom layout. There are other tools for that - e.g. you can publish your modules (apps) to PyPI (public one or self-hosted), or you can browse open source libs and see how they handled multi-app projects and directory layout.